# Responsive Theme 2 column layout - wrap text under widgets in right column

Tags: themes, css

I have been working on this for a bit and am not savvy enough to know how to correctly implement it (such that it remains a responsive design).

I am running the free "responsive" wordpress theme by ThemeID on a test site and need to have the main body content text of the single article page wrap underneath the right sidebar and adjust "dynamically" as the sidebar changes height over time. I plan on having the "Archives" widget in this right sidebar, so over time it will grow in height...so the body text should not extend to underneath the sidebar until it reaches the bottom of the sidebar. Take a look at a mockup I made real quick to demonstrate what I mean.

Before: http://www.heliossolutions.net/responsive.jpg

After 2: http://www.heliossolutions.net/responsive3.jpg

As you can see, the text currently leaves a huge white space beneath the sidebar but I would like for it to be able to flow underneath and adapt to the sidebar height. It also needs to maintain the responsive nature of the theme and work correctly on mobile devices (i.e. the sidebar widgets should properly display underneath all the content when viewed on a mobile phone, as it does out-of-the-box).

Does this make sense?

The page code currently looks like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="template" content="Responsive 1.6.9" />
    </head>
    <body class="single single-post postid-36 single-format-standard">
    <div id="container" class="hfeed">
            <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
            </div><!-- end of #logo -->  
                    <ul class="menu"><li >Home</li></ul>
        </div><!-- end of #header -->
            <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <div id="content" class="grid col-620">
                <div id="post-36" class="post-36 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-web-development">
                    <div class="post-meta">
                    <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author">Posted on </span> July 2, 2012</span>                                          
                    </div><!-- end of .post-meta -->
                         <div class="post-entry">
                             <p>Post content here.Post content here.Post content here.Post content here.Post content here.Post content here.Post content here.Post content here.</p>                    
                         </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->
                    <div class="post-data">
                    </div><!-- end of .post-data -->             
                <div class="post-edit"></div>             
                </div><!-- end of #post-36 -->
            <div id="respond">
                <h3 id="reply-title">Leave a Reply <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/blog/parallax-slider/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>
                        <p class="must-log-in">You must be logged in to post a comment.</p>
</div><!-- #respond -->
               </div><!-- end of #content -->
               <div id="widgets" class="grid col-300 fit">
                    <div class="widget-wrapper">
                    <div class="widget-title">In Archive</div>
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                </div><!-- end of .widget-wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- end of #widgets -->    </div><!-- end of #wrapper -->
        </div><!-- end of #container -->
    <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <div class="grid col-940">
            <div class="grid col-540">
                     </div><!-- end of col-540 -->
             <div class="grid col-380 fit">
             <ul class="social-icons"></ul><!-- end of .social-icons -->         </div><!-- end of col-380 fit -->
             </div><!-- end of col-940 -->
            <div class="grid col-300 copyright">
                &copy; 2012
            </div><!-- end of .copyright -->
            <div class="grid col-300 scroll-top"><a href="#scroll-top" title="scroll to top">&uarr;</a></div>
            <div class="grid col-300 fit powered">

            </div><!-- end .powered -->
        </div><!-- end #footer-wrapper -->
    </div><!-- end #footer -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the corresponding CSS (tried to give you more than enough, since I can't pinpoint the exact issue):

```
#content {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.grid {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:2.127659574468%;
    padding-top:0;
}

.col-60, 
.col-140, 
.col-220, 
.col-300, 
.col-380, 
.col-460, 
.col-540, 
.col-620, 
.col-700, 
.col-780, 
.col-860 {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:2.127659574468%;
}

.col-620 {
    width:65.957446808511%;
}

.post-meta {
    clear:both;
    color:#9f9f9f;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.post-entry {
    clear:both;
}

.post-data {
    clear:both;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:700;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.post-edit {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:1.5em 0;
}

#widgets {
    margin-top:40px;
}

.col-300 {
    width:31.914893617021%;
}

.fit {
    margin-left:0!important;
    margin-right:0!important;
}


.widget-wrapper {
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
    border-radius:6px;
    font-size:13px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
    padding:20px;
}


.clearfix:after, 
#container:after, 
.widget-wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"\0020";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
}


.clearfix, 
#container, 
.widget-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
}

.clearfix, 
#container, 
.widget-wrapper {
    display:block;
}
```

Any ideas as how to do this? I know it is possible and probably a simple change, I'm just not adept enough at responsive CSS to see it!

Thanks,
D

[4/9/12 - Updated HTML code to show entire page, with extra Head info (javascript and style sheets) removed]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because your HTML is not complete (most of the divs are not closed for example). However, both .widget-wrapper and .col-300 have bottom margins which if remove might do the trick.

Comment: Henrik, Thanks for your reply. There is not a bottom margin on both of these elements. But even if I do remove all margins from these two, it still doesnt work as needed.

Comment: @user1508056: Ok. The code you provided above does not seem to match the code used in your "After 2" image. Could you update the code so that it is the same as the one used in your screenprint? This jsfiddle shows the provided code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/kZKyd/

Comment: Thats the code I am looking for. The screenshot is just a mockup, not a live site. It looks a tiny bit different (in terms of the right column content/height) because I pulled the base image source from a different theme page. It is the same underlying code as that provided above.